# VBA Excel check for duplicated values in rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a raw data like that in excel:

[**Doc number**]      [**Inv number**]      [**Description**]      [**Amount**]

I want to check if **Inv number** exist in other row and then check if the sum of **Amount** between those rows are 0. (One row will be negative number)

The document could be 3000 rows of more. The purpose is to check accounting movements.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your columns above (IE. `Col A = Doc Number`, `Col B = Inv Number` etc):

```
=SUMIF(B:B,B:B,D:D)
```

Use this formula in E:2 and copy it down. Column E will then hold the sum of matching Inv Numbers